# Permanently mounting a samba-shared-folder on a RPI to my Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: server, mount, samba, fstab

I've got an RPI running Ubuntu server 18.04 and have set up a samba server there to share /home/user/sambashare. I used [these instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview) to get that up and running.

In the same network I have an old computer, also running Ubuntu server 18.04, and I would like to mount that sambashare to /media/share permanently.

I've installed cifs-utils on this old computer and added the following line to the /etc/fstab:

```
/pi_name/home/user/sambashare /media/share cifs uid=0, credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,nounix 0 0
```

Of course, .smbcredentials contain the username and password.

But all I get when I try to `sudo mount -a` is `mount error(2): No such file or directory`

I am a Linux novice and I have spent the best part of two days browsing through various tutorials with these subjects, but I can no get this working. Any tips that could put me on the right track?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You'll need to include the IP for the remote server. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1208598/968501) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax errors there when specifying the network address of the share.

[1] It has to start with double slashes //

[2] And it's //server/share not //server/internal/path/to/shared/folder.

So replace `/pi_name/home/user/sambashare` with `//pi_name/sambashare`

And make sure /media/share exists.

And more of a side note: Accessing a host by name ( netbios name ) is kinda flakey so you might want to access it by ip address ( //192.168.0.100/sambashare for example ) or if this is a Linux, MacOS, or Win10 host by it's mDNS name ( //pi_name.local/sambashare )

Comment: Thanks a billion! [1] was actually a copy/paste error - I had that one. But [2] was not on my radar at all! Not quite sure if I understand why accessing by host name is scetchy - but I'm sure your right and have made a mental note of that :-D Thanks again, sir!