# What is the simplest way to check that a filesystem is really mounted?

Tags: networking, mount, fstab

The simplest way to ensure that a filesystem listed in **fstab** is really mounted is to include the attribute **_netdev** in the relevant line.  Unfortunately it doesn't always work! If the **mount** operation depends on something else being already mounted, the **_netdev** attribute is insufficient.  This situation is discussed a length in [how to setup ubuntu that fstab runs after network is connected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208568/how-to-setup-ubuntu-that-fstab-runs-after-network-is-connected).

But that solution looks fairly complex to me. So is there a simple way to check if a filesystem is surely mounted that works under all circumstances -- in other words, provides a foolproof way of achieving what **_netdev** tries to achieve?

Comment: Does the mount need to exist before a login? If not, then having a script run at login that checks if a device/location is mounted and taking an appropriate action may be one way to ensure everything is in place 

Comment: Read `man mountpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lsblk
```

You should see the NAME of the device in the first column and the MOUNTPOINT in the last column.

As a bonus, you get some other columns such as SIZE and TYPE in a human readable format.