# Mount Network Drive Permanently in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, 22.04, automount, cifs

I want to mount a LAN Network Drive that I can access from Files/Nautilus as soon as I login to my Ubuntu desktop.

I can do this manually with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=user,password=***,vers=1.0  //192.168.XX.XX/sda1 /media/sda1/
```

If I reboot the system, I loose the file location of my drive and find myself running the command again. Another manual method that works is by :

Cntrl+L and then typing smb://192.168.XX.XX/sda1/

Can you recommend me a tutorial that will allow me to accomplish my goal or let me know the steps to mount this Network drive that is attache to my router BTW.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to setup ubuntu that fstab runs after network is connected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208568/how-to-setup-ubuntu-that-fstab-runs-after-network-is-connected)

Answer (score 0):

## Custom script option with crontab

1. Create .sh script
2. Add your line without sudo:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 mount -t cifs -o user=user,password=***,vers=1.0  //192.168.XX.XX/sda1 /media/sda1/
```

3. Add privileges

```
sudo chmod 700 ./your_script.sh
```

4. Add owenrship to the root user

```
sudo chwon root:root ./your_script.sh
```

5. Modify your contab as sudo user by adding following line

```
sudo corntab -e
```

```
@reboot sleep 30 && /bin/sh /full_path_to_file/your_script.sh
```

### Description

Crontab will lunch your script 30 seconds after reboot (to avoid situation when some services are waking up when you lunch the script)

Ad. 3 and Ad. 4 - Will protect you script, that only users with sudo privileges can read/write/execute.

Ad. 5 - Use `sudo crontab` to lunch jobs as root user.

---

## Fstab option:

1. Create file with credentials:

```
sudo nano /etc/cred_1
```

```
username=myUser
password=my$Password!
```

2. Privileges for read/write

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/cred_1
```

3. Open fstab and add line with cifs mount

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

```
//192.168.100.100/folder /home/mnt cifs credentials=/etc/cred_1,users,uid=114,gid=1002,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770 0 0
```

- uid,gid is an user/group id: `id username`.
- file_mode and dir_mode was used because cifs doesn't support umask argument.