# How to Mount ReadOnly storage in Ubuntu

Tags: server, mount

I have ubuntu server & have one cpanel hosted website, I do want to mount my cpanel hosted storage to be mounted at my ubuntu drive, I do want it to be readonly.

or basically can we access files from IP directly?

Data available at 103.xx.xx.xx/Storage/ this location & accessible from my browser, But I do want to access it as external read only storage from my ubuntu server

Comment: All you need to do is add `ro` to the mount options for Read Only.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I dont understand what you mean

Comment: If you look at answers like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208568/how-to-setup-ubuntu-that-fstab-runs-after-network-is-connected that show you how you can add network storage as a mount to your system, after the credentials= is the options.  I would say after something like the `noauto,` I would add `ro,` for the read only option.