# network drives not getting mounted after reboot

Tags: networking, mount, fstab, cifs

we have a ubuntu 22.04 server.
we are mounting network drives from a windows server. The drives are mounted correctly but don't get mounted back when we reboot the Ubuntu server.

below are the contents of the `/etc/fstab` file

```
//192.168.88.110/g /mnt/nl-dev-g cifs username=user,password=password,rw 0 0
//192.168.88.110/v /mnt/nl-dev-v cifs username=user,password=password,rw 0 0
```

but when we reboot the **`Ubuntu`** server, the drives do not get mounted on startup.

any help on what could be going wrong here would be really helpful.

Comment: That is most likely because those mounts are attempted early before network comes up ... Please see for example [how to setup ubuntu that fstab runs after network is connected?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1208568)

Answer (score 1):

Network mounted drives vanish when the Windows server goes down.

When the Windows server becomes visible on the network, no notification is sent to Ubuntu (Windows doesn't remember what network mounts it was serving last time, so doesn't know who to notify).

Ubuntu doesn't want to simply resume the mountedness, because the filesystem being mounted (or the rules governing sharing on Windows) may have changed.

You *could*, for each of the mountpoints (in the background), loop on using the `mountpoint` command to check the status of the mount, then loop on "is Windows up?" (I'd `ping -c3 Windows` and check `$STATUS`), then remount (`mount -o remount ...`) the network drive.

`man mountpoint ping bash mount sleep`

There are probably better answers out there.

Comment: hi waltinator, sorry for the confusion, my issue happens where ubuntu server restarts and not the windows server