# External USB SSD disk fails to mount at boot

Tags: boot, mount, ssd, usb-drive

I have two external drives attached to my Ubuntu Server 22.04.3. My `/etc/fstab` includes, among other things, the following two lines for the two drives:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d7dbea69-0332-4d12-b905-b9a116e28422 /sandisk ext4 auto,nofail 0 2
/dev/disk/by-uuid/06b24834-a749-4d93-b0d5-a6da71eaf224 /verbatim ext4 auto,nofail 0 2
```

`/verbatim` is an independently powered magnetic disk also attached via USB. It gets detected and mounted on boot just fine.
`/sandisk` is the problem. This is a USB SSD drive with no power. I can mount it fine **after** boot with `mount -a` but the system always boots with it not mounted. Is there any way I can have it mounted at boot?

Comment: Perhaps the SSD isn't ready and needs a delay. Try a `systemd.mount` + a `systemd.timer`

Comment: Although not a network device but, [how to setup ubuntu that fstab runs after network is connected?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1208568) might help delay the system trying to mount that until it's ready with power.

Comment: Another boot parameter that may help? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fstab#Automount_with_systemd  or you can use autofs https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs
use autofs for any storage that isn't connected directly to the system with SAS, SATA, eSATA, or Infiniband connections

Answer (score 0):

My kernel ring buffer contained all the information I needed.

```shell
$ sudo dmesg
...
[    2.770637] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=55af, bcdDevice=40.55
[    2.770642] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[    2.770645] usb 2-1: Product: Extreme Pro 55AF
[    2.770646] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[    2.770648] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 323332314230343031393737
...
[   60.108257] EXT4-fs (sdb): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[   60.125838] EXT4-fs (sdb): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
```

So **it was being detected** during boot! A simple `sudo e2fsck -y /dev/sdb` fixed the problem.